# Grant read-only access to the Public role for a specific dashboard without any extra permissions in Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I would like to grant read-only access to the user for an available dashboard. I know that one can grant such access with the [RBAC flag](https://superset.apache.org/docs/creating-charts-dashboards/creating-your-first-dashboard/#manage-access-to-dashboards). However, it occurs to me that this does not work if you don't give custom permissions to the Public role, such as the ability to view dashboards. One way to do it is to give Alpha permissions with the [PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE](https://superset.apache.org/docs/security/#public). However, this has the unwanted side effect of allowing the user to click around and get access to parts of the UI that they shouldn't see, such as the chart editing UI.

My current approach is as described - give Alpha permissions to the Public role. This makes it possible to view the dashboard through a direct link and to embed it into a webpage. However, it also allows the user to enter other parts of the UI, as already explained. I would like a cleaner solution that would allow me to present to the user **only** what the dashboard displays, including any filters I have created for it. Is there a way to achieve this?